# Update textarea with JS/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using Gridster for webpage.The widgets have images on it.These images can be added and deleted with `+` and `X` button.

There are two `<textarea>` fields on widgets.

One with

```
class="hoverinformation" \\ it captures title attribute for image
```

and other with

```
class="imagenames"\\it captures image src.
```

**Expected Output**

1. When I delete all the exisiting images and add a new image.Both `<textarea>` should update.

2.When I remove any image both the `<textarea>` should update(remove `src` and `title` for that image)

JS:

```
 //To delete an image
$(document).on('click', '.removediv', function () {
  $(this).closest('div.imagewrap').remove();

  //Here I want that will remove the content from both the textareas

});



//Adding Images from Modal

    var parentLI;
    $(document).on("click", ".addmorebrands", function() {
                    parentLI = $(this).closest('li');
            $('#exampleModalCenter').modal('show');
                $('#exampleModalCenter img').click(function(){
            $(this).addClass('preselect');
            $(this).siblings().removeClass('preselect');
            selectedImageSRC = $(this).attr('src');
          })
        });


      //To add an image
    $('#add-image').click(function(){
        parentLI.append('<div class="imagewrap"><img class="images" src="'+selectedImageSRC+'" title="Manual Addition"> <input type="button" class="removediv" value="X" /></div>');

      parentLI.children('.imagenames').append(', '+selectedImageSRC);
      parentLI.children('.hoverinformation').append(', '+"Manual Additon");

      $('#exampleModalCenter').modal('hide');
    });
```

I have tried different ways with it but they are not giving the desired output so someone who can go over it please help

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sz4wcLgo/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you looking for: https://jsfiddle.net/sz4wcLgo/52/

```
function trimChar(string, charToRemove) {
    while(string.charAt(0)==charToRemove) {
        string = string.substring(1);
    }

    while(string.charAt(string.length-1)==charToRemove) {
        string = string.substring(0,string.length-1);
    }

    return string;
}

function updateTextarea(imageNames, imageSrc) {
  var imageNamesValue = imageNames.val();
  imageNamesValue = imageNamesValue.replace(imageSrc, '');
  imageNamesValue = trimChar(imageNamesValue, ',');
  imageNames.val(imageNamesValue.trim());
}
```

//Function to delete an image from widget

```
$(document).on('click', '.removediv', function () {
  var imageDelete = $(this).closest('div.imagewrap');
  var imgTag = imageDelete.find('img');
  var imageTitle = imgTag.attr('title');
  var imageSrc = imgTag.attr('src');

  var textareaName = $(this).closest('li').find('.imagenames');
  var textareaTitle = $(this).closest('li').find('.hoverinformation');

  updateTextarea(textareaName, imageSrc);
  updateTextarea(textareaTitle, imageTitle);
  //Here I want that will remove the content from both the textareas
 imageDelete.remove();
});

$('#add-image').click(function(){
    parentLI.append('<div class="imagewrap"><img class="images" src="'+selectedImageSRC+'" title="Manual Addition"> <input type="button" class="removediv" value="X" /></div>');
  var imageNameValue = parentLI.children('.imagenames').val();
  var imageTitleValue = parentLI.children('.hoverinformation').val();
  if (imageNameValue === '') {
    parentLI.children('.imagenames').val(selectedImageSRC);
  } else {
    parentLI.children('.imagenames').val(imageNameValue +', '+selectedImageSRC);
  }
  if (imageTitleValue === '') {
    parentLI.children('.hoverinformation').val("Manual Addition");
  } else {
    parentLI.children('.hoverinformation').val(imageTitleValue+','+"Manual Addition");
  }


  $('#exampleModalCenter').modal('hide');
});
```

Comment: Yeah This is it !! Thanks for your help

Comment: My `src` is of the form `/static/images/imagename.png` Since I am doing that in server.So how can I extract only `imagename.png` from the `src` and delete it from `textarea`

Comment: You can use `split('/')` to get filename

Comment: Thanks for that as well Working perfect :)

Comment: How are you accessing `selectedImageSRC` in the `#addimage` function.Because it is defined in the function above it.

Comment: If you don't define `selectedImageSRC`. This variable will be global.

Comment: I was just not understanding the scope of that variable.Since it is defined in this function `$(document).on("click", ".addmorebrands", function() {` how is it accessible in this  `$('#add-image').click(function(){
` .Because `selectedImageSRC` would be local variable to this `$(document).on("click", ".addmorebrands", function() {` function. How are we accessing it outside its function even when it is not global

Comment: If you defined like `var selectedImageSRC = $(this).attr('src');` inside `$(document).on("click", ".addmorebrands"`. The `selectedImageSRC` will be undefined in `$('#add-image').click`. and if you missing `var`, this variable will be global

Comment: If an image between the two images is deleted  then the `,` remains can you please help with that

Comment: You can check my function `trimChar`. I used this to trim `,`

Comment: If there are 3 images and if 1 or 3 image is deleted its perfect.But when 2 image is deleted the `,,`  remains

Comment: You need to trim again when you delete image? I run `var a = ',aaaa,,,'; trimChar(a, ',')` and It seem working fine

Comment: Check here https://jsfiddle.net/ahx0rp4k/  the widget with 3 images.If you delete middle image the `,,` remains for them

Comment: I do not see any output when I run it

Comment: No problem :) Do you want me to post a new question and you address it there if that's fine with you

Comment: No problem then. I just want to help :). BTW, If you have any further support, please create new question. This topic is too long for now.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).on('click', '.removediv', function() {

var container = $(this).parents('.gs-w'),
namesContainer = container.find('.imagenames'),
titlesContainer = container.find('.hoverinformation'),
newNames = [],
newTitles = [];

$(this).closest('div.imagewrap').remove();

container.find('div.imagewrap').children('img:visible').each(function(){
newNames.push($(this).prop('src'))
});

container.find('div.imagewrap').children('img:visible').each(function(){
newTitles.push($(this).prop('title'))
});

titlesContainer.val(newTitles.join(','));
namesContainer.val(newNames.join(','));

});
```

New Fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/edh4131/cxyp2a0j/6/

Comment: This will clear the textarea entirely I just want to delete the content for image which is deleted.Correct me if I am wrong

Comment: Sorry bro, let me update, I misunderstood what you meant here: "When I remove any image both the <textarea> should update(remove src and title for that image)", I thought you wanted to remove both. I'll update your fiddle

Comment: @NewBie updated, here's a new fiddle, sorry for the delay I had to go do something real quick. https://jsfiddle.net/edh4131/cxyp2a0j/6/